# Google _trackEvent not working

Tags: analytics, tracking

I'm having an issue with google analytics trackEvent.

I'm using the following code -- and after several days and several 1,000 visitors l'm not seeing anything recorded in my google analytics.

So at the top of my page l am including my google analytics tracking code (and of course jquery), and at the bottom of my page, and before the closing  tag l have the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(["_trackEvent", "Funnel", "SOMETHING HAPPENED", "page1.php", 0, false]); // create a custom event
});
</script>
```

Any help?

Comment: Are you using Universal Analytics or classic GA? The syntax you use to track events depends on which version. The code you provide is based on classic GA. Also, what kind of an event are you tracking that would require the code to be at the bottom of the page?

Comment: I see, that may be the problem. How do l tell if l'm using universal or classic? I think l'm using universal but dunno how to tell for sure.

Comment: Try this: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/4457764?hl=en